# GroovyClassLoader support for lazy compile using loadClass() is this possible

Tags: groovy

Does GroovyClassLoader support for lazy compile using loadClass() ?

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @tim_yates if I have a "Class_A" that depends on "Class_B", and I do... ParseClass("Class_A"); groovy will see that Class_A depends on Class_B so it will load classb , basically building a custom Groovyclassloader

Answer (score 0):

extends the GroovyClassloader and override the loadclass method

```
@Override
    public Class loadClass(String name, boolean lookupScriptFiles,
            boolean preferClassOverScript) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            CompilationFailedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        Class<?> loadedClass = super.loadClass(name, lookupScriptFiles, preferClassOverScript);
        if (loadedClass !=null) {
            return loadedClass;
        }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("here --------------");
        }

         int indx = name.lastIndexOf('.');
            String substr = name;
            if (indx != -1)
            {
                substr = name.substring(indx + 1);
            }
            String groovyFileName =  substr + ".groovy";
            String path = "C:\\" + groovyFileName;

            try
            {
                return parseClass(new File(path).toString(), groovyFileName);
            }
            catch (CompilationFailedException exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
    }
```